# Create .d.ts for both a module.exports = function and some interfaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, .d.ts, typescript-declarations

I have a javascript code similar to this:

```js
module.exports = function foo(language, platform, milliseconds) { 
   // some code
}
```

This code should be placed in a **module** ("mymodule") that will be imported through **npm**.

I want to create the corrisponding **.d.ts** file.

I have something like this:

```
declare module 'mymodule' {
     export type Language = 'it' | 'es' | 'de';
     export type Platform = 'linux' | 'winzoz';
     export function foo(language: Language, platform: Platform, milliseconds?: number): void;
}
```

But of course it did not work. I tried:

1. ```
   declare module 'mymodule' { export default function foo(myparams: Types): void; }
   ```

   But this did not work, because I am using `module.exports = function f()` and not a default export
2. ```
   declare module 'mymodule' { function foo(myparams: Types): void; export = foo; }
   ```

   But this did not work, because it says that I should use `esModuleInterop` or use an ugly `import foo = require('mymodule')`. It does not include the interfaces that I want to export, too.

How can I solve these problems?